# How to fire a callback function after a for-loop is done in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, callback

I have two functions that caluclate and adjust the height and width of elements on screen.

**panelHeight** sets the height of target elements to the available screen height, while **panelWidth** adjusts the width of elements.

**My problem:**
I cannot ensure the second functions (*panelWidth*) fires AFTER the first function (*panelHeight*) is done. If the target element is long and has a scrollbar, it will be removed by *panelHeight* but if this is not done before *panelWidth* fires, the set width will be off by the space taken up by the scrollbar (17px - still present when the width is calculated).

**So I'm looking for a way to fire a function only after another function is done.** Sort of like a callback, but I'm not sure who to fiddle this in below for-loop:

```
panelHeight: function (from) {
    var self = this,
        o = self.options,
        wrap = $('div:jqmData(wrapper="true").ui-page-active').last(),
        overthrow = wrap.jqmData("scrollmode") == "overthrow" && $('html').hasClass('ui-splitview-mode'),
        blacklist = $('html').hasClass('blacklist'),

        // calculationg toolbars
        // elements
        contents = TARGET_ELEMENT;

    if (overthrow) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++){
            // calculate values 
            ...
            contents.eq(i).css({    
                        "max-height": setH, 
                        "margin-top": blacklist == true ? glbH + lclH : 0, 
                        "margin-bottom": blacklist == true ? glbF + lclF  : 0
                    })
            }

        } else {

            for ( var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++){
                // calculate values
                ...
                contents.eq(i).css({    
                            "max-height" : "", 
                            "height": o._iPadFixHeight, 
                            "margin-top": blacklist == true ? 
                                parseFloat( lclH.outerHeight() ) : 0, 
                            "margin-bottom": blacklist == true ? 
                                parseFloat( lclF.outerHeight() ) : 0
                        })
                }

            }   
            // USING THIS NOW, WHICH IS NOT NICE                
    window.setTimeout(function(){ self.panelWidth(false ); },65)
    },
```

So I'm either looping through the overthrow-if-or-else loop and only need to fire **panelWidth** **AFTER** the loop is finished.

**Question:**
Any idea how to get rid of the timeout and add the *panelWidth* function call to the end of the loop? I tried with *queue*, but this also requires a *delay(xxx)*. Also I cannot fire panelWidth inside the for-loop. I need it to trigger once only once the height function is complete

**EDIT**:
Would this be possible:

```
// calling my panelHeight function like this: 
self.panelHeight("source").done(function() {
   // call panelWidth:
   self.panelWidth();
   });
```

If so, where would I have to put the *var deferred = Deferred();*?

**SOLUTION**:
Got it to work. Thanks all! Here is my solution:

**When calling panelHeight**, add done() handler

```
$(document).on('pagechange.fixedHeight', function() {
    self.panelHeight("pagechange").done( function() {
        self.panelWidth( false ) 
        });
    });
```

Inside **panelHeight**, declare defer and return resolved();

```
panelHeight: function (from) {  
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    ... run function

    return deferred.resolve();
    }
```

Comment: You don't have async functions in your code. And thus all code is blocking, there is no need to use a callback, just call the function at the end of your code. If this does not work, the problem is not the time of the call but rather something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the purpose of the JQuery [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)...

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

somethingAsync(function() {
    // callback stuff here

    // now tell the deferred task it's ok to proceed
    deferred.resolve();
}

deferred.done(function() {
    // your finalize code here
});
```

<s>**Edit**
Since the *resolve* event needs to be tied to a dom resizing, maybe the Javascript [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event handler would work.</s>

Comment: Ah. I always wondered what deferred does. So in the callback I put my function code and in the deferred.done() I call my panelWidth function?

Comment: @frequent yes, right.  I'm actually not sure this helps you though ... normally to use deferred you would *resolve* in the callback, but there's no callback in this case, is there?

Comment: nope. The above function just runs and only once it's done, I need the other function to fire. Playing around with deferred now. I post if it works

Comment: Yes, that's the correct usage.  See my update, it might work to tie the *resolve* to the *resize* event.

Comment: @frequent nevermind, *resize* is only for the *window*.  It looks like you're going to need a JQuery plugin to detect the resize event.  http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

Comment: I'm inside my own plugin :-), I'm checking inside Jquery Mobile now, which uses it a lot to see if I can get it to work.