# Callback function after reading multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-io

I am doing something similar to http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

What I'm doing is Im reading the contents of the selected files one at a time to validate that their lines pass some regex test. After done validating all files, I need to update (enable / disable) some buttons accordingly hence the call back function

Is it possible to have a call back function which will do something after everything is read?

#### HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
```

#### Javascipt:

```
<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var validArray = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        //Create new file reader
        var r = new FileReader();
        //On load call
        r.onload = (function (f) {
            return function (e) {
                var contents = e.target.result;
                var lines = contents.split('\n');
                
                for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
                    //Validate regex of line here
                    //If line does not pass, append file name to validArray and break  
                }
                                
            };
        })(f);
        r.readAsText(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Comment: The code does not to what you think it does. Every time you select a file, the `ul` is cleared and rewritten with the full list of files, which is kept in the `output` array (which is exactly the array you are looking for maybe). What is that you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Hmm. maybe I simplified my example too much. What I'm doing is Im reading the contents of the selected files one at a time to validate that their lines pass some regex test. After done validating all files, I need to update (enable / disable) some buttons accordingly hence the call back function
I will update the question with the details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Came here looking for a similar answer. I wanted to call a function after all files were loaded and processed. The solution provided by @Snuffleupagus did not work for me because the function was called after all the files were read, but before they had finished being processed in the onload function. I found a solution around this as follows (not sure if it is the 'cleanest' but it works for me).

```
var processedCount=0; // global variable
var totalFiles = 0; // global variable

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  totalFiles = files.length; // important

  // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    //Create new file reader
    var r = new FileReader();
    //On load call
    r.onload = (function(theFile){
        return function(){
          onLoadHandler(this,theFile);
          onLoadEndHandler();
       };
    })(f);
    r.readAsText(f);
  }
}

function onLoadEndHandler(){
  processedCount++;
  if(processedCount == totalFiles){ 
    // do whatever - this code will run after everything has been loaded and processed
  }
}
```

I tried to use r.onloadend but it was called too soon. I believe because my function 'onLoadHandler' takes a few seconds to process each file and onloadend is called when the file is done being loaded but before the code within 'onload' has finished running.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Callbacks are just passed as any other normal argument would be, so we'll end up adding another argument to `handleFileSelect` and changing the event listener to an anonymous function that calls `handleFileSelect` with the extra argument.

I set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bSdsM/) to give you a quick working demo.

```
function handleFileSelect(evt, cb) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>'+ escape(f.name) + '</strong>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
    if(cb) cb();
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', function(e){handleFileSelect(e, function(){alert('all done');})}, false);​
```

Breaking it down - added an extra argument to `handleFileSelect` and at the end added `if(cb) cb();`. That just checks to see if cb exists, if it does, run it as a function.

Then when we go to bind the event handler instead of passing a reference to `handleFileSelect` we use an anonymous function - this lets us pass our extra argument.

The anonymous function inside of the anonymous function is just our callback, it could be a reference to a function if you'd rather.

Comment: Ah sweet! Exactly what I was looking for!
Thank you!

Comment: @Omar Sure, just add an extra argument for the callback and wrap the event listener with an anonymous function to pass it.

Comment: I tried this
var readAndValidateCallback = function(e){readAndValidate(e, function(){alert('all done');})}
But it did not call the call back, could you make a fiddle with my updated code?

Comment: The callback is being called BEFORE everything

Comment: @Omar How do you figure? You mean before the text is appended?

Answer (score 1):

A really clean way to do this is to use [async.js reduce](https://github.com/caolan/async#reduce) method.  [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) gives many nice ways to deal with multiple callbacks.  You could use reduce to iterate through the array of file names, and build a reduced value which is an array of the valid lines:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://github.com/caolan/async/raw/master/lib/async.js'/>
<script>
var isValidLine = function(text){
// todo: implement
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    // reduce by starting with empty array in second argument - 
    // this gets built up with the valid array lines
    async.reduce(files, [], function(validLinesSoFar, file, callback){
        var r = new FileReader();
        // Read file here:
        r.onload = function (f) {

            var contents = f.target.result;
            var lines = contents.split('\n');

            for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
                if isValidLine(lines[i])
                    validLinesSoFar.push(lines[i]);    
            }
            callback(null, validLinesSoFar); 
        };

        r.readAsText(file);
    }, function(err, validLines){
        // gets called after every file iterated through
        // result is entire valid array
        // do something here with valid array
    });
}

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at jQuery's [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Also a very relevant question that might be applicable to you.

[How to fire a callback function after a for-loop is done in Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046456/how-to-fire-a-callback-function-after-a-for-loop-is-done-in-jquery)