# slideDown() after slideUp()

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

On a click of a button slideUp a div, after it's up - clean the content, create rows in that div and populate the rows with data, after everything is done - slideDown the div. I wrote this code (which is being called on page load and when one of the buttons is clicked:

```
function create_rows()
{
$(".div_rows_container").slideUp(400, function(){
    $(".div_rows_container").html("");
    for(var i=0; i<arr_pros.length; i++)
    {
        if(arr_pros[i].pro_area==curr_area)
        {
            $("<div id='row_id_"+arr_pros[i].pro_id+"' class='div_row'></div>")
                .appendTo(".div_rows_container");
            populate_row(arr_pros[i], i)
        }
    }
    $(".div_rows_container").slideDown(400);
});
}

function populate_row(pro, i)
{
    var row_id = "#row_id_"+pro.pro_id;
    $("<div class='div_pro_name'></div>").html(pro.pro_name).appendTo(row_id);
    $("<div class='div_pro_address'></div>").html(pro.pro_address + ", " + pro.pro_city).appendTo(row_id);
    $("<div class='div_pro_phone'></div>").html(pro.pro_phone).appendTo(row_id);
}
```

It does slide up, clears the content, creates rows and populates them, but it doesn't slide down. It just shows me all the rows at once. So how can I make it also slide down?

Comment: What does populate_row do? (As in what does the code look like?)

Comment: It just adds some divs with content to each row that's being created on iteration. I updated my question with the code.

Comment: And there's only divs involved? No tables? Because table rows objects have no effect from slideDown and slideUp (except being hidden/shown as you describe)

Comment: pls share JSfiddle if you can and you should use 'this' reference for html clear and slideDown like $(this).html('');

Comment: Only divs, no tables at all.

Comment: I tried to recreate the code with jsfiddle, and one I was done I realized that my code was working just fine, however due to pretty short slide time and long list the sliding animation was very hard to see. http://jsfiddle.net/z32tt/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

    function create_rows()
    {
    $(".div_rows_container").slideUp(400, function(){
        $(".div_rows_container").html("");
        for(var i=0; i<arr_pros.length; i++)
        {
            if(arr_pros[i].pro_area==curr_area)
            {
                $("<div id='row_id_"+arr_pros[i].pro_id+"' class='div_row'></div>")
                    .appendTo(".div_rows_container");
                populate_row(arr_pros[i], i)
            }
        }
    });
        deferred.resolve();
    }

    deferred.done(function() {
        $(".div_rows_container").slideDown(400);
    });

    function populate_row(pro, i)
    {
        var row_id = "#row_id_"+pro.pro_id;
        $("<div class='div_pro_name'></div>").html(pro.pro_name).appendTo(row_id);
        $("<div class='div_pro_address'></div>").html(pro.pro_address + ", " + pro.pro_city).appendTo(row_id);
        $("<div class='div_pro_phone'></div>").html(pro.pro_phone).appendTo(row_id);
    }
```

Please check for reference here: [How to fire a callback function after a for-loop is done in Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046456/how-to-fire-a-callback-function-after-a-for-loop-is-done-in-jquery)

and about the Deferred Object:

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Please let me know if it works cause I'm wondering too, good luck.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but alas it didn't work - I only got a result (again with regular rows, without slideDown) on page load. When I clicked the buttons I only got the slideUp and that's it.